# is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{i \in I}(x^n_i) =\sup_{i \in I}(\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^n_i)$? for each i, $x_i^n$ is a monotone increasing sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Is $\displaystyle{\lim_ {n\to \infty} \sup_ {i \in I} (x^n_i) =\sup_ {i \in I} \ \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^n_i)\right)}$ ?
For each $i \in I$, $(x^n_i)_{n \in N}$ is a monotone increasing sequence. We can write $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^n_i) = x_i$. I don't know how to start approaching this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (I'll be adding parentheses on the exponent-index just for my personal taste. Doesn't change anything.)

Try to first prove that the limit on the left side exists and is a $\sup$ using the "$n$-monotony" of your sequences, so that what you want to prove becomes:

$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)} = \sup_{i \in I} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)}\,\,?$$

From there, you should be fine hopefully.

Comment: A good tip with $\sup$-related questions like this one, or even with equalities in general: try to proceed by double inequality, i.e. try to show that one is lesser than the other and vice-versa. As for the $\sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$ parts, it's all about the definition: you want to show that $\sup(B)$ is an upper bound of set $A$, and then use that $\sup(A)$ is by definition the smallest upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time has passed, so I'll answer this fully now.

Since $\left(x_i^{(n)}\right)_n$ is increasing, we have, for all $i \in I$ and all $n$: $$x_i^{(n+1)} \geq x_i^{(n)}$$
By taking the $\sup$ on the left side, we get, for all $i$: $$\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n+1)} \geq x_i^{(n)}$$
Since the left side is constant compared to $i$, we can take the $\sup$ on the right side, which grants:
$$\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n+1)} \geq \sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}$$
Therefore, the sequence $\left(\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}\right)_n$ is also increasing, which implies that all $\lim$s in the starting equation exist and were all $\sup$s, meaning that what we wanted to prove is equivalent to:
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)} = \sup_{i \in I} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)}\,\,\,?$$

Let $i \in I$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We have, quite trivially:
$$x_i^{(n)} \leq \min\left(\sup_{i \in I}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)}, \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}\right)$$
By then taking the $\sup$s in two different ways, we obtain:
$$\max\left(\sup_{i \in I}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)}, \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}\right) \leq \min\left(\sup_{i \in I}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)}, \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}\right)$$
Hence:
$$\max\left(\sup_{i \in I}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)}, \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}\right) = \min\left(\sup_{i \in I}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)}, \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}\right)$$
which finally yields:
$$\sup_{i \in I}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_i^{(n)} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{i \in I} x_i^{(n)}$$